# Invalid procedure call or argument in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a filter on column1 of sheet1 with a unique no, get filtered values from column Z into an array (arr) object and paste those values as a string in one cell in "Dashboard" sheet. Repeat this process for all unique values on column 1 of sheet1. I am getting multiple errors 1. "Invalid Procedure call or argument" at Join() method. 2. Getting values into rng object and array. Can I get your help on where am I going wrong with this. Many Thanks.

```
Dim d As Object, c As Range, k, tmp As String
Dim TestRg As Range
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim myCell As Range
Dim rng As Range
i = 2

Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Columns(1).Select
For Each c In Selection
    tmp = Trim(c.Value)
    If Len(tmp) > 0 Then d(tmp) = d(tmp) + 1
Next c

For Each k In d.Keys
If IsNumeric(k) Then
 Set TestRg = Range("A1:AQ" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
 TestRg.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=k, Operator:=xlFilterValues
 LasRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
 Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("Z1" & ":" & "Z" & LasRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 rng.Activate
 arr = rng.Value
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A" & i) = k
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("E" & i).Resize(UBound(arr, 1)).Value = Join(arr, " ")
i = i + 1
Erase arr
End If
Next k
```

Comment: Possible cause of this is the range length that you specified exceeds to the length of data you are calling on your code.

Answer (score 0):

as for the very error your post is asking help for, it comes out of:

```
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("E" & i).Resize(UBound(arr, 1)).Value = Join(arr, " ")
```

since `arr` is a ***Two***-dimensional array while [Join()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264098(v=office.15).aspx) function requires a ***One***-dimensional one

you then should:

- declare arr as a *simple* Variant:

  ```
  Dim arr As Variant
  ```
- fill it in a way so as to generate a *One-dimensional* array

  ```
  arr = Application.Transpose(rng.Value)
  ```

other than that it seems to me your code have some more issues

you may want to fix this error first and then, should those issues actually arise and shouldn't you be able to fix, make a new post

Comment: @Ram, did you get through it?